# Can I have a 4 GB RAM (1600 MHz-1.35V-DDR3) and a 2 GB RAM (1333 MHz-1.5V-DDR3) at the same time to my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, performance, speed

Currently my laptop has a:

- 4GB RAM DDR3, 1.35V, 1600MHz.

I am wondering if I could add to the other slot of my laptop another RAM which has the following specs:

- 2GB, RAM DDR3, 1.5V, 1333 MHz

so, overall my new system will have 4 + 2 = 6 GB of RAM

Is it possible or may I face any problem in the future due to different frequency, voltage and capacity?

Thank you

Comment: The difference in voltage and speed likely will present problems.

Comment: Not sure about SODIMMs, but for DIMMs the 1.35v ones run at 1.5v (which is a JEDEC standard) but also support other voltages. So mixing them should be possible and both should run at 1.5v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be a problem - your faster RAM will be downclocked to run at the speed of the slower stick, however, apart from in benchmarks you are unlikely to notice the difference and the extra 2GB of RAM will be an improvement.

Worst case scenario is it doesn't boot and you can remove the second stick without a problem, but it should be compatible without issue.